# SP Designer Workflow not firing in email enabled discussion list

Tags: designer-workflow, workflow-activity

I have enabled incoming email in a discussion board list and I can receive emails correctly.

I want to trigger a workflow when emails are received or when items are added. I have a workflow but it is not firing. What am I missing to trigger the workflow correctly upon those events ?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Designer workflows **won't** trigger when you're **logged in as farm account / system account**.

Make sure you're logged in as a different user for testing / triggering workflows.

Comment: Since it is a email enabled document library , by default it will use System account.